# Send JSON to GET method in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-core, http-headers, webclient

I have a web service with a controller that looks like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Customizing.RequestSizeLimit(1048576)] // 1 MB
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status422UnprocessableEntity)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ValidateTicketAsync([FromBody]KerberosTicketDto ticket)
    {//code in here//}
```

Swagger states the web service accepts:

```
{
"ticket": "string"
}
```

From the client, I get a Kerberos ticket and convert it to a string:

```
KerberosSecurityTokenProvider tokenProvider = new KerberosSecurityTokenProvider(ServiceServer, TokenImpersonationLevel.Identification);
KerberosRequestorSecurityToken token = tokenProvider.GetToken(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)) as KerberosRequestorSecurityToken;
...
tokenString = Convert.ToBase64String(token.GetRequest());
```

Then attempt to send the data to the web server, and return a response code (i.e. hopefully 200):

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.QueryString.Add("ticket", tokenString);
//webClient.QueryString.Add("spn", ServiceServer);
string result = webClient.DownloadString(urlTest);
```

The debug windows then sends me this:

```
[10:40:21 DBG] Attempting to bind parameter 'ticket' of type 'Kerberos.TicketValidator.WebApi.Model.KerberosTicketDto' using the name 'ticket' in request data ...
[10:40:21 DBG] Rejected input formatter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.JsonPatchInputFormatter' for content type 'null'.
[10:40:21 DBG] Rejected input formatter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.JsonInputFormatter' for content type 'null'
```

It appears the parameter the web service gets is not the type it expects it to be.

Can anyone help me in converting it to the right type? Or how to send it as the right type in the first place?

Thank you!

Comment: `FromBody` with `HttpGet` ... fascinating

Comment: I did not code the api, I am testing it.

Comment: swagger shows some json ... try to send json like in swagger in **body** of HTTP request ... there is only one problem HTTP GET is not intended to have body

Comment: Just to get it straight: `public async Task<IActionResult> ValidateTicketAsync([FromBody]KerberosTicketDto ticket)` is _not under your control_, you are only supposed to test it. Is that right?

Comment: Fildor, that is correct.

Comment: Should be a `POST` request if you're getting anything `FromBody`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to send the ticket as an object with a property called `ticket` not as as string.

With [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) it could be something like the following.

```
var tokenJson = jsonSerializer.Serialise(new {token = tokenString });
using(var client = new HttpClient())
{
  var req = new HttpRequestMessage
  {
      Method = HttpMethod.Get,
      RequestUri = new Uri("some url"),
      Content = new StringContent(tokenJson, Encoding.UTF8, ContentType.Json),
  };

   var res = await client.SendAsync(req).ConfigureAwait(false);
   res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

   var res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try.